# Gradle doesn't see Spring packages, but have a dependency declared

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I'm working on my new project. But when I try to build it, gradle return the error:

```
 error: package org.springramework.transaction does not exist
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
```

and

```
error: package org.springramework.orm.hibernate5 does not exist
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.4.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat'

compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

def tomcatVersion = '9.0.22'
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
            "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:8.5.2",
            "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion},"

    testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-all', version: '1.3'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '1.8.4'
}

tomcat {
    httpProtocol = 'org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol'
    ajpProtocol  = 'org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNio2Protocol'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-dbcp:9.0.22'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.6'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-context:5.1.8.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.1.8.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-orm:5.1.8.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-tx:5.1.8.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.1.Final'
}
```

There is no error about spring context imports.
I know, this is very strange, but in folder 
`~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework` there are both spring-orm and spring-tx folder with jars.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You miss spring-transaction as dependency.

Comment: I used your build file for a brand new gradle project, tried to import and use PlatformTransactionManager, and it worked absolutely fine. Try removing the .gradle directory and do a clean build.

Comment: There is "spring-tx" dependency. JB, I tried your suggestion. And it still doesn't work.